# Mimic XCode UIBarButtonItem init with an image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I was trying to create programmatically a `UIBarButtonItem` with an image.

I went like this :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L-large-star@2x.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]
```

With that method my icon gets upscaled (and it's ugly). When I create that same button from the Interface Builder, the icon is a the right size (1/2 of the button).

Any idea how I could mimic this ?

Comment: What do you mean by upscaled? Can you share a picture of what you expect to see vs what you are actually seeing?

Comment: my 22x22 icon shows up as an ugly 50*50px icon.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the `L-large-star@2x.png`?

Comment: 22*22 as I said above.